# Does angularJS support routing and object persistence?

Tags: ember.js, angularjs

I'm comparing both ember.js and angularJS and what I like about ember currently is the Router and ember-data (soon to be part of the core framework I hope).

Does anyone know if angularJS supports these 2 features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ember.js but from what I can understand from reading ember's docs there are mechanism in AngularJS that should be (roughly) equivalent:

1. Routing mechanism in AngularJS is handled by the $route service. Example / tutorial here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07
2. As for data access there is high-level $resource mechanism (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11), quite good at interacting with REST endpoints.

Both mentioned services ($route and $resource) are great for standard use-cases but show some limitations for more advanced use-cases. Fortunatelly there are always lower-level fallback options ($location for $route and $http for $resource).

I hope that someone more familiar with ember.js will be able to comment more.